# xslt start select after $$$ but retain xml formating

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following structure...

```
<story><p>£££ Some Name $$$story text text text etc</p><p>more text text text etc</p></story>
```

I have been trying to use substring-after to select the text after `$$$` and was planning on concatenating a `<p>` to the start. However I lose all my tags using this method. I'm struggling to create a template solution with the correct syntax to do this.
desired output -

```
<story><p>story text text text etc</p><p>more text text text etc</p></story>
```

can anyone help. thanks Angela

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="VirtualComCMS">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="VirtualComCMS"/>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="VirtualComCMS">

    <xsl:for-each select="articles/article">
      <Article>
        <xsl:element name="StoryID">
          <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
        </xsl:element>
        <Name>
          <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        </Name>
        <ModificationDate>
          <xsl:value-of select="ModificationDate"/>
        </ModificationDate>
        <CreationDate>
          <xsl:value-of select="CreationDate"/>
        </CreationDate>
        <Headline>
          <xsl:value-of select="Headline"/>
        </Headline>
        <Subheadline>
          <xsl:value-of select="Subheadline"/>
        </Subheadline>
        <Story>
          <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="p/text()[contains(., '$$$')]">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '$$$')"/>
          </xsl:template>
              <xsl:copy-of select="Body/div/node()"/>

        </Story>
        <Summary>
          <xsl:value-of select="Summary"/>
        </Summary>
        <Keywords>
          <xsl:value-of select="Keywords"/>
        </Keywords> 
        <Latitude>
          <xsl:value-of select="latitude"/>
        </Latitude>
        <Longitude>
          <xsl:value-of select="longitude"/>
        </Longitude>
        <Categories>
          <xsl:value-of select="Categories" />
        </Categories>
        <!-- <Categories>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(Categories, '/' ),'/')" />
         </Categories>
        <SubCategories>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(Categories, '/' ),'/')" />
        </SubCategories>-->
        <Priority>
          <xsl:value-of select="Priority"/>
        </Priority>
        <Byline>
          <!-- check story -->
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(Body/div/p, '$$$')">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(Body/div/p, '$$$'), '£££')" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="CreatedBy"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
           </Byline>
        <Images>
          <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <xsl:element name="Image">
               <xsl:attribute name="id">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
               <!--<xsl:attribute name="fileext">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@ext"/>
              </xsl:attribute>-->
              <xsl:attribute name="filename">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ImageToSaveID,'.jpg')"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="urlpreview"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Images>
      </Article>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>




</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post your expected result, and explain what you mean by  "*I lose all my tags using this method*". -- Keep in mind that XSLT does **not** process your input *as text*; you cannot "concatenate" a tag to the start of text.

Comment: Hi - @michael-hor257k  my desired output would be as above what I currently get is story text text text etc more text text text etc without tags thanks Angela

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question is entirely clear, but to get you started:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()[contains(., '$$$')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '$$$')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to you example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<story>
  <p>story text text text etc</p>
  <p>more text text text etc</p>
</story>
```

Comment: hi , thanks for helping Michael how do i call this template..if i add it inside story tag I get an error. template cannot be a child of story

Comment: @AngelaBaines What tool are you using to do the XSL transformation?

Comment: I am afraid I know very little about that. In general, you need to provide two **separate** files: (1) your XML input (as shown in your question) and (2) an XSLT stylesheet (which would contain the code shown above).  You should not try and combine the two manually.

Comment: hiya, sorry you've misunderstood me...im not putting the xsl into the xml file...the story tag is in the xsl file as above..

Comment: Templates must be at the top level of your stylesheet. i am afraid I cannot help you any further that that, because I don't know what the other parts of your stylesheet are supposed to do.